# Django PostgreSQL search returning fewer than expected results

Tags: django, postgresql

Say I have the following `queryset` of carrots:

```
<QuerySet [
    <Carrot: Blue carrot>, 
    <Carrot: Purple carrot>, 
    <Carrot: Apple carrot>, 
    <Carrot: Yellow Carrot>, 
    <Carrot: Green carrot>
]>
```

I can filter for `<Carrot: Apple carrot>` by using:

```
queryset.filter(name__icontains="app")
```

However, if I try the same filter with [PostgreSQL's search lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup):

```
queryset.filter(name__search="app")
```

I get an empty queryset. Why is this? I would expect that PostgreSQL's search lookup would return results for partial word matches.

Is there a way to relax the constraints of `__search` so that I can use the feature as a backend for a typeahead search field?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark ... Is __search also case insensitive?

Comment: can you confirm you've added `django.contrib.postgres` to your installed apps?

Comment: @ptr yes I've added `django.contrib.postgres` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. @yrekkehs no, if I do `queryset.filter(name__search='apple')` I get the `<Carrot: Apple carrot>` object.